# How to lock a Rust struct the way a struct is locked in Go?

Tags: rust, locking, mutex

I'm trying to learn how to do locks in Rust the way they work in Go. With Go I can do something like:

```golang
type Info struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    height    uint64 
    verify bool
}
```

If I have some function/method acting on info I can do this:

```golang
func (i *Info) DoStuff(myType Data) error {
    i.Lock()
    //do my stuff
}
```

It seems like what I need is the sync.RWMutex, so this is what I have tried:

```
pub struct Info {
    pub lock: sync.RWMutex,
    pub height: u64,
    pub verify: bool,
}
```

Is this the correct approach? How would I proceed from here?

Comment: This question doesn't show research effort. [Searching the Rust docs for "rwmutex"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html?search=rwmutex) points to [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) which has examples. There's also [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) in the same module, also with examples.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't understand how those examples relate to structs, sorry.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't do it the Go way, do it the Rust way. [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) are generic types; you put the data to be locked **inside** of them. Later, you access the data through the *lock guard*. When the lock guard goes out of scope, the lock is released:

```
use std::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Info {
    data: RwLock<InfoData>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct InfoData {
    height: u64,
    verify: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let info = Info::default();
    let mut data = info.data.write().expect("Lock is poisoned");
    data.height += 42;
}
```

The Go solution is suboptimal as nothing forces you to actually use the lock; you can trivially forget to acquire the lock and access data that should only be used when locked.

If you **must** lock something that isn't the data, you can just lock the empty tuple:

```
use std::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Info {
    lock: RwLock<()>,
    height: u64,
    verify: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let mut info = Info::default();
    let _lock = info.lock.write().expect("Lock is poisoned");
    info.height += 42;
}
```

See also:

- [What do I use to share an object with many threads and one writer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27359586/155423)
- [When or why should I use a Mutex over an RwLock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50704279/155423)

Comment: "If you must lock something that isn't the data", so in this case, what am I really going to lock? In C++, it seems that Mutex is used to lock code.